# Getting different EC public key length using Bouncy Castle and OpenSSL

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption

I use Bouncy Castle lib in my C# project, that generates Elliptic Curve keypair. The curve that I use is brainpoolP256r1 and when I check returned key using cryptii.com it shows that it's 65 byte array for public key as it must be. But when I try to generate key using openSSL and then check it in Cryptii it is 92 byte.

I am using the following commands in openSSL:

```
openssl ecparam  -name brainpoolP256r1  -genkey  -noout  -out key.pem
openssl ec -in key.pem -out public.pem -pubout
```

what i'm doing wrong?

[image]

Generated public key:
`MFowFAYHKoZIzj0CAQYJKyQDAwIIAQEHA0IABGFETzBdIgNwFDZN86O4R1MfCzSEPV3G46IW7S08VXXpNEPcqMJ5/nzYZM6hS6A0LkHBoxeJmnNLsgoohlQmmHE=`

Comment: I can't actually copy&paste the bytes because they're in a picture, not text. Pictures are pretty but less useful.

Comment: Thank you for answer, here is the key `MFowFAYHKoZIzj0CAQYJKyQDAwIIAQEHA0IABGFETzBdIgNwFDZN86O4R1MfCzSEPV3G46IW7S08VXXpNEPcqMJ5/nzYZM6hS6A0LkHBoxeJmnNLsgoohlQmmHE=`

Comment: That public key is in a format with more metadata, the **SubjectPublicKeyInfo** format, and is described in [RFC 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280). You can view it decoded [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MFowFAYHKoZIzj0CAQYJKyQDAwIIAQEHA0IABGFETzBdIgNwFDZN86O4R1MfCzSEPV3G46IW7S08VXXpNEPcqMJ5_nzYZM6hS6A0LkHBoxeJmnNLsgoohlQmmHE). As always, the format you need to use depends on what you are going to do with this public key.